# How to discover the referrals to 404 error pages in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, 404

I want to know the source of traffic which is directing people and bots to a page that does not exist on the site.  As a result they are being getting to a 404 page. How can I find this info using Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

This could work if your 404 page has a specific title (like 'error' or 'Page not found'):

In Analytics: Go to Behavior > Site Content > All Pages
As primary dimension choose 'Page Title' and filter on the title of your 404 page - this will list all traffic to you 404 page.
Then choose 'Full Referrer' as secondary dimension - which will give you the url's linking to 404 pages. Disadvantage is that you don't know the page which is generating the 404.

Another alternative: create a custom report (under Customization tab)

Select Type: Flat Table

Dimensions: Page + Page Title

Filters: Page Title - Regex: (title of your 404 page)

=> Save (and run) - this generates a report with url / page title / referrer.

Alternatives: check the search console - it lists which pages are linking to your 404 pages. The method above will only work for humans - most bot traffic will not be measured by analytics